# How to use Array in Oracle's bpelx:exec BPEL extension

Tags: java, soa, jdeveloper, bpel

I have created a BPEL process in which there are two java Embed Activity.and we have on varibale(array type) at BPEL process level.

following is the array variable xsd.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/RegistrationUpload_jws/RegistrationUpload"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <element name="groupIDArray">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="groupId" type="string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>      
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

My requirement is I want to add variables in this array on Java Embed activity and then I will use the same filled array in next Java Embed activity.

Please suggest me some points. 
any sample code if possible please refer the link.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What's you problem, exactly?

- Before calling Java Embedded, call getVariable(), which will give you the variable (array) as a DOM Element.
- Pass it down to Java code.
- Parse it there into a data structure (JAXB is best for it).
- Add/remove/update elements as you wish.
- Serialize the data structure back to DOM.
- Return it from Java.
- Call setVariable() to store the DOM back into the original variable.

You're done, the variable is updated.